# Using odeint in sicpy and in sympy to solve the ordinary differential equations, the result is different

Tags: python, scipy, sympy, ode

When I use scipy to solve ordinary differential equations, the results obtained are different from those of sympy. Specifically, they are different after the decimal places, and there is no imaginary part.

Since the ordinary differential equation I need to solve is the first symbol solution obtained by sympy, I first converted it with sympy.lambdify and then brought it into the scipy.odeint method.

Here is part of the code

```py
    t = sy.symbols('t')  
    y_0_t_func = sy.Function('y_0')
    tspan = np.linspace(0, 10, 10)

    def y_0_Q_x(t):

        return sy.nsimplify(
            (lambda_1 * pow(A_0, 2) * F_0 * P_theta *
             (k_0 + beta * (function_B_0(t) / function_B_1(t)) - F_0 *P_theta)
             - (lambda_2 / 2) * pow(function_B_0(t) / function_B_1(t), 2) +
             y_1_t.rhs * (alpha - F_0 * P_theta + x_1_t.rhs)))

    f_y_0 = sy.lambdify((y_0_t_func(t), t), r * y_0_t_func(t) - y_0_Q_x(t))
    y_0_numerical = np.flipud(
        integrate.odeint(f_y_0, g_2 * S_Ba, np.flipud(tspan)))

    y_0_t = sy.dsolve(
        sy.nsimplify((sy.diff(y_0_t_func(t), t, 1) - r * y_0_t_func(t) 
        +y_0_Q_x(t))),
        y_0_t_func(t),
        ics={y_0_t_func(10): g_2 * S_Ba})

    sy.pprint(y_0_t.rhs.evalf(subs={t: 0}))
    print(y_0_numerical[0])
```

The result of the program is

```
-951.483500299349 - 2.98155597433514e-19⋅ⅈ
-951.48350659
```

Comment: The code provided is incomplete. Please add a minimal sample that defines all sympy symbols.

Comment: In any case your numerical result is close to the analytical result. The difference in the real part is less than 1 part in 1e8 which is the expected tolerance for odeint. The imaginary part is a tiny and comes from rounding error. I can't diagnose why there is an imaginary part at all though with the incomplete code provided here